# Microsoft visual studio 2005 has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Everything was going fine but the next day, when I opened the visual studio It showed error as

[image]

this error occur at every project files and at the starting.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the VS again but also nothing is improved. when I started my pc in safemode , in that case visual studio runs fine however when I opened in normal mode , It shows the error.

Also using command like devenv or devenv/safemode or devenv/resetsettings pops the same error message.

Comment: It is the kind of crash that occurs on a 64-bit operating system.  Your VS version is very old and wasn't originally designed to run on such an OS.  Very important to get the service packs installed, SP1 first, then the special one that made it better suited to run on Vista.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience and from what I've heard from others, VS2005 has problems on newer OS's and needs to be *run in a XP VM* for reliable results.  Some editions of Win7 have a nice transparent way of doing that for software that doesn't like newer OS's, but the VM component needs to be installed first.

I also recall VS getting fouled and needing to be ripped out and re-installed to work again.  In your case, re-installing from original media did not include all the service packs and patches, and it probably only worked at all due to updates and a bit of luck.  You might try restoring from a backup rather than re-installing, but it's really a lost cause.